# What are the python equivalent of sem_init, sem_post, sem_wait provided by semaphore.h?

Tags: python, semaphore

I'm trying to lock multiple variables in a piece of python code that I have, one lock per variable. Variables can be easily locked in C using sem_wait, sem_post, sem_init routines available in semaphore.h. What are the equivalent in python?

Addendum:

Currently using a code structure equivalent to

```
lock1 = threading.lock()
lock2 = threading.lock()

Thread 1
lock1.acquire()
var1 = func1()
lock1.release()
lock2.acquire()
var2 = func2()
lock2.release()

Thread 2
lock1.acquire()
var1 = func1()
lock1.release()
lock2.acquire()
var2 = func2()
lock2.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the "threading" module in the standard library. It provides semaphores, locks and other parallel processing niceties.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html

Answer (score -1):

In most python implementations, you have a Global Interpreter Lock that prevents more than one thread at a time from executing python code.

Additionally, in most implementations, the GIL is only released after certain numbers of complete python bytecode operations have executed, meaning that, unlike C, you don't have a situation where load-increment-store operations could run in parallel and be done incorrectly -- in general, changes to variables are atomic.

Hence you usually don't need to protect each variable, and you'll find that a lot of code actually 'just works', depending on how you are using python threads.

Having said that, the Threading module (particularly condition variables) is the way to go if you need tighter grained control beyond what the GIL implicitly provides.